# Sort results by number of matching words

Tags: mysql, order-by, sorting

I have a table (called sentences) in which I have some sentences. I want people to be able to search it with multiple words, which would make the SQL query look like this:

```
SELECT content FROM sentences WHERE content LIKE "%<word1>%"
                                 OR content LIKE "%<word2>%"
                                 OR content LIKE "%<word3>%" etc... ;
```

How can I sort the results by the number of occurrences of different words, the most matching sentence comes first, etc...?

Comment: Oh boy that's going to be super slow and rexource hungry almost makes it not usable if you want to do that . you need to use full text search and sort the result by score

Comment: `ORDER BY content LIKE "%<word1>%" + content LIKE "%<word2>%" + content LIKE "%<word3>% ... DESC`

Comment: @Akina this doesn't really seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

Add a fulltext index on content and use "match", as in

```
SELECT *, match(content)
  against ('you surround' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) as score
  FROM Sentence
  Order by score desc
```

See this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/47)